# php vendor и .dockerignore, как не удалять из финального образа

Tags: php, docker, composer, dockerfile

Создаю контейнер для приложения на php-fpm, для уменьшения build context добавил директорию `vendor` в `.dockerignore`, но после билда в финальном образе эта директория удаляется (на этапе билда он создается с помощью composer install). Я так понимаю это так ведет себя механизм .dockerignore, как можно сделать так, что бы в build context директория vendor не передавалась, а в финальном образе эта директория не удалялась?

Вот пример моего Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

ENV DB_HOST=app_mysql

RUN set -ex \
    && apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates mysql-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/*

VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app

RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction

#smoke test composer vendor directory
RUN ls -lah /app/vendor
```

Вот пример моего .dockerignore

```
*
!/src
!/public
!/composer.json
!/composer.lock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть решена, за счет multi-stage build, т.е. мой Dockerfile выглядит следующим образом:

```
FROM composer:1.9 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./composer.json /app/composer.json
COPY ./composer.lock /app/composer.lock
COPY ./symfony.lock /app/symfony.lock

RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction --no-scripts

FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine as app
ENV DB_HOST=app_mysql

RUN set -ex \
    && apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates mysql-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/*

VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
COPY --from=builder /app/vendor /app/vendor

RUN composer dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize --no-scripts

#smoke test composer vendor directory
RUN ls -lah /app/vendor
```